# For loops to iterate through two lists in an sql query, one of these lists is made up of smaller lists

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, sqlite

I have large databases for which I am using an sql query in python to write the data to csv files. In the sql database each row is a series of spatial information for a finger ID. I can parametize the query to get the information and write the files I need for each finger. However, the problem arises in creating a functional for loop that iterates over each ID for all the indexes in the list.

```
INDEX = ([44,48,50,55,56,57], [49,54,57,61,62,64])


FINGER = ('rt100', 'rt101')

d = {}
newdf = {}

for Y in FINGER:
    for X in INDEX:
        for x in X:
            d[x] = pd.read_sql ("SELECT x,y, CAST( (direction*180/3.142)as INT),CAST(quality*100 as INT) from UTS_7_fingerprints where finger like ? and ind = ?", conn, params=(Y,x))
            newdf[Y] = pd.concat(d)
```

The script above runs the sql query and creates a dictionary of concatenated dataframes successfully. However for each FINGER value it is iterating over the entire INDEX list.

Looking like this:

```
{'rt100':      finger ind  ... CAST( (direction*180/3.142)as INT) CAST(quality*100 as INT)
44 0  rt100  44  ...                                281                       93
48 0  rt100  48  ...                                303                       32
49 0  rt100  49  ...                                281                       13
50 0  rt100  50  ...                                123                       82
54 0  rt100  54  ...                                281                       14
55 0  rt100  55  ...                                314                       67
56 0  rt100  56  ...                                123                       88
57 0  rt100  57  ...                                314                       71
61 0  rt100  61  ...                                326                       11
```

This is an example for one of the FINGER values. I need it to be iterating over only [44,48,50,55,56,57] for 'rt100' and [49,54,57,61,62,64] for 'rt101'. Currently it is iterating through all the values within INDEX.
In reality I have many more similar correspondences hence the need for a query that takes these parameters.

To be more specific, I'm looking for a way to limit how this loop runs in order to write each query for each FINGER and INDEX to seperate .csv files that look like this:

```
372,402,281,83
394,303,303,97
415,422,123,86
458,328,292,95
464,487,112,96
483,389,303,95
```

Where each line is information:

```
'x,y, CAST( (direction*180/3.142)as INT),CAST(quality*100 as INT'
```

for each INDEX within each FINGER.

Comment: Is the database really sqlite? If yes do you have a strong reason for not using the sqlite3 module which can do much more efficient queries?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

> However for each FINGER value it is iterating over the entire INDEX list

And it is caused by this loops:

```
for Y in FINGER:
    for X in INDEX:
        # whatever
```

In this case `whatever` will be executed for all combinations of values from `FINGER` and `INDEX`. If each has `N` values the `whatever` line is executed `N*N` times.

But you want it to only execute for some of them, namely given `FINGER = [f1, f2, ..., fN]` and `INDEX = [i1, i2, ..., iN]` there should be exactly `N` iterations for values `(f1, i1)`, `(f2, i2)`, ... , `(fN, iN)`.

To do this change the loop:

```
for Y, X in zip(FINGER, INDEX):
    # whatever
```